# Select automatically the correct language based on keyboard hardware

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I have this laptop with an English keyboard and an usb French Keyboard.
French Keyboard in the office and English while travelling.

Is there a way that Windows (Seven) picks the right input keyboard layout based on the key typed on the keyboard hardware?

The idea is that, if I input text with the "English layout" hardware, the layout is English and if I input text using the French keyboard hardware, the layout is set to French keyboard...

Answer (score 0):

*"Is there a way that Windows (Seven) picks the right input keyboard layout **based on the key typed** on the keyboard harware?"*

In your keyboard settings you find that key: control panel > keyboard and languages > change keyboards: if you go to the tab "advanced key settings" you can define a key combination to set the keyboard to french and another one for the keyboard to go to english.

So if you define that "key" to a logical one: it will will change.

Furthermore : if you activate the language bar on the top and assign a nice logical icon to the keyboards (via general > properties) e.g. a "flag" you can also continuesly see which language is active (although it will also display it in the text next to it)